# Considering Transmission Line Effects for Clock Generator

Tags: clock, transmission-line, impedance-matching, vhf

I'm trying to design a clock circuit to convert a 50 MHz 5-volt clock signal down to 3.3 volts without inverting it. The concept is relatively simple, but as I never designed anything like this from scratch before, I'm beginning to look into concepts that I never considered in designing circuits. For the scope of this question, lets limit it to the output signal.

Assuming that I manage to generate a 3.3 voltage clock source at 50 MHz, the signal has to travel across a SMB cable, for now at most 6 feet (1.83 meters), to a NIM module, whose connector has a 50 ohm impedance at its inputs. This got me thinking about transmission lines in general. When using other devices that require a coaxial connection, such as an oscilloscope, I've used various lengths of cables to connect from a source to them, and the signal stays relatively intact with minimal voltage drop. At 50 MHz in the very high frequency range, I would assume that there will be some voltage drop from the generator output to the NIM module input, but aside from matching the impedance at the output of the generator, is there anything I can do to mitigate the probable voltage loss across the line?

Sorry if the question is unclear. I was just thinking about this since cables come in various lengths, and signal generators tend to produce waveforms within significant tolerance since there's no guarantee way to match the characteristic impedance for every length. I'm just trying to design it in such a way that I don't have to rely on a certain cable of a certain length, so if the situation arises, my team can use a different length cable.

For a rough reference, here's a quick and dirty schematic of how I roughly imagine this problem to be. The input port of the module may have a 50 ohm impedance, but I'm not sure if you could treat it as a 50 ohm load in a schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKOLIz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you really want specifics, I'm working under the assumption that the cable is coaxial, with copper for the conductors and teflon for the insulator. The cable itself is 2.489 mm in diameter while the center conductor is 0.508 mm in diameter.

Comment: if the coaxial cable has a characteristic impedance of 50 ohms, it will be 50 ohms no matter the length. The voltage drop will depend on the length of coaxial cable and the quality, although it will probably be quite low at 50 MHz

Comment: @JorenVaes, even at DC there's a voltage divider formed by the source impedance and the load impedance, which reduces the signal voltage by half (assuming you do have source termination).

Comment: @ThePhoton ofcourse, but the cable does not change this and assumign a lossless cable (which I think is valid for a few meters length at 50 MHz) the lenght of the cable will not impact this behavior.

Comment: OP, are you stuck using full-swing CMOS logic signals? Often when working with 50 ohm lines it makes more sense to use ECL or some other logic family that is designed to work with such a heavy load.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your reply. I'm not entirely sure if you would consider me 'stuck'. The NIM module input is limited to 3.3 V, so not necessarily, as long as 0 V is still low, and 3.3 V max (as seen by the module) is logic 1. Like Joren Vaes mentioned, with the voltage drop, I could increase the voltage to 6 V to get the 3 V output at the other end, but this is still on paper for now. What worries me is the load impedance (module's internal circuit). You can't assume that its 50 ohms; I would imagine its much greater than that, so the voltage wouldn't necessarily be 3.3 V there?

Comment: You absolutely need to find out what the load termination actually is. There are schemes that will work if the load is well-matched to 50-ohms. There are schemes that will work if the load is high impedance. But it would be much more difficult to make a design that would work for either one.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your reply. Is there a better way to find out the load termination other than just using an ohm-meter and measuring the resistance between the input pin and ground?  Also, I guess this made me think of another thing. You can't test the load termination of every oscilloscope, yet signal generators manage to produce a solid waveform with little to no reflection (virtually) regardless of the coaxial cable used. How could I do the same thing here?

Comment: You could check the documentation. Or use a network analyzer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your answer. I don't have a network analyzer handy, so I'll check the documentation. Sorry, but I just want to run something by you. If you assume a lossless line, the characteristic impedance and phase velocity is just determined by the cable used, and length has no effect on them as a parameter. What other assumptions can you make with the lossless line? I'm thinking that it might be simpler to make this assumption.

Comment: As said by Photon it is essential to know if the NIM module has 50R termination on its input or not. A multimeter will not help if the input is AC-coupled and the termination resistor is on the other side of the cap. Since this is an essential spec to be able to use this equipment at all, it will be in the manual...

Comment: Most likely it will not have input termination. So you can convert 5V to 3.3V logic levels with a buffer in the 74LVC family running from 3.3V, LVC has 5V-tolerant inputs. You can also use a resistive divider with an output impedance matching the cable, if the 5V clock can output enough current. What generates the 5V signal? Does it have a buffer on the output or is it just a canned oscillator? Is phase noise, jitter, or a stable propagation delay very important here? (logic gates have temperature-dependent propagation delay so this information matters)

Comment: @peufeu Thanks for your comments and your suggestion about the 74LVC. The 5V signal is an external clock from another source, and I suppose stability and the phase difference between the clocks is key, but I'm not addressing the 5-3.3 V conversion right now. That's another question. I'm just trying to analyze here the TL effects of the 3.3 V clock as it leaves the generator. The NIM has inputs rated for 50 ohms; is that what you're referring to? The connector may be rated as such, but that's just the connector and not the internal circuitry of whatever's inside the module.

Comment: @user101402, the very first sentence in your posts talks about converting from 5 V to 3.3 V. From that I, at least, assumed this was an important part of your question.

Comment: You can always send a 3.3V signal with a fast rise time from a 50R source-terminated function generator through a cable, into the input, put a BNC tee on the input, and probe it with the X10 probe from your scope. Then post the shape of the signal. It will look different if the input is terminated or not.

Comment: Also, check the required level of that clock input, I would be very surprised if it really needs 3.3V into 50 ohms up it. Usually a 50 ohm terminated clock input will be designed to work with signals in the -10dBm to +10dBm range, more or less, and while 3.3V might be a maximum I would be surprised if it was required.